# Can't find `a2dissite` and `a2ensite` after building `apache2` from source on Mint17

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apache-httpd, compiling

After building *apache2 http server* from source (*2.4.23*) 
I don't have the `a2dissite` and `a2ensite` commands.

Configure was:

```
./configure --with-included-apr --prefix=/usr/local/apache2
```

When I run:

`whereis apache2`

I get:

```
apache2: /etc/apache2 /usr/local/apache2
```

But `which apache2` shows nothing, maybe there needs to be some symlinking to `/usr/bin`?  `http://localhost` is working fine.

Version info for source:

`/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov  1 2016 22:52:26`

Linux version:

```
linux mint 17
3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64
```

Comment: Why 1) are you building it from source? 2) not making an effort to create a deb minimally compatible with Debian/Mint?

Comment: @ Rui F Ribeiro 1)wanted to try out such a thing by myself. 2) this will be the next thing to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you built from the source available from the Apache Software Foundation. The `a2en...` scripts (and the supporting configuration) are Debian-specific; you'll find the source code in the corresponding [Debian repository](https://salsa.debian.org/apache-team/apache2/blob/master/debian/a2enmod).

Your best bet to build the `httpd` server from source and still be able to use `a2ensite` etc. is to use the Debian source package:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts dpkg-dev build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep apache2
dget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.23-5.dsc
cd apache2-2.4.23
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

The first two commands install the packages necessary to build `apache2`; then `dget` downloads and extracts the source package, and `dpkg-buildpackage` builds it and produces a series of `.deb` packages you can install manually using `dpkg` as usual.

If the `build-dep` line doesn't work, the following is equivalent for `apache2`:

```
sudo apt-get install debhelper lsb-release libaprutil1-dev libapr1-dev libpcre3-dev zlib1g-dev libnghttp2-dev libssl-dev perl liblua5.2-dev libxml2-dev autotools-dev gawk dh-systemd
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't symlink things to `/usr/bin`. That is an extremely bad idea and you should not do it.

Why? Because most of `/usr`, including `/usr/bin`, is reserved for the package manager. Anything that is not a package manager, including you, shouldn't be touching things in there.

`/usr/local` exists to provide a place to install locally-compiled software. Normally, you would provide `/usr/local` as a prefix, instead of `/usr/local/apache2`. (A prefix, by the way, is what's prefixed to the bin path, the library path, etc. So e.g. Apache's commandline tools would go in `$PREFIX/bin`, its libraries would go in `$PREFIX/lib/apache2`, etc.)

The solution to your problem is to add `/usr/local/apache2/bin` to the list of paths your shell uses to find binaries. This is usually referred to as `$PATH` or simply "your path", and can be changed with a command like:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/apache2/bin:$PATH"
```

You can put that in one of your shell's startup files to make it permanent.

That all being said, I suspect you still won't find `a2ensite` or `a2dissite`. If I recall correctly, both of these commands were added by Debian developers and then inherited from there by Mint. Therefore, they aren't included in upstream Apache source code. Stephen Kitt's [excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320424/29146) will tell you how to get these commands.